# Apache2 fail in Linux Mint 17 KDE

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

- I am with Linux the 5th day only.
- I am used to XAMPP based projects in Windows, where everything is out-of-box and easy.
- But unreadable cyrillic letters in GitBash (when typing `ls -la`), file names no longer, than 256 symbols and absolutely non-secure access to non-public project folders forced me to switch to Linux Mint 17 KDE (Debian - Ubuntu fork).
- After long searches in Internet I did all that is mentioned below.
- I am absolutely frustrated with fact that when I type in browser address bar my first PHP script with `<?php phpinfo();` inside (`http://site1/foo.php`) - everything is OK.
- However the second (e.g. bar.php), the third (start.php) etc. scripts from the same folder - ERROR (no such file on server).
- I made different sets of scripts in ~/server/site2 and ~/server/site3 and the necessary commands.
- I made different parent folders (server2, html, sites).
- I cleared Firefox cache.
- The result is the same: the first script in a newly created folder is OK, - all the following ones - FAIL.

Any ideas?

Here is the code https://yadi.sk/d/Vi4VVho3bN3Ps

Comment: Use ls -l to make sure the permissions and owner are the same on those php files

Comment: I missed to say: I did it of course.
`drwxr-xr-x` - for folders
`-rw-r--r--` - for files

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have comment ability yet but just so you know, you can use XAMPP on Linux, however it is generally not recommended outside of development.

Comment: Thank you. - Yes, I know about it, therefore I would like to use traditional LAMP stack approach and I still hope to cope with LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
According to `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/` I needed *Name-based Virtual Hosts (More than one web site per IP address)* described here `http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html`.
For this I needed to uncomment or create `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive in `httpd.conf`.
However, here `https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Debian.2C_Ubuntu_.28Apache_httpd_2.x.29:` is stated that debian based linux distros use two config files (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`) instead of classic `httpd.conf` one.
Neither of my two config files had `NameVirtualHost *:80` directive.
Therefore, I created it in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.
This didn't work even after checking access rights to folders and files in my user folder (644 instead of 755 also OK) and `sudo a2dissite site1.conf`, `sudo a2ensite site1.conf`, `service apache2 reload`.
I made PC reboot - and voila! - I see my virtual hosts in browser.